# Scheduling chained tasks with celery and celery beat

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I'd have some tasks that I'd like to chain together in celery, and I'd like to schedule this with celery beat.

The included code *works*, but the docs seem to imply that calling tasks within tasks is a bad idea in terms of efficiency and potential deadlocks. Docs: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

Simplified version of my code:

```py
# tasks.py
from my_proj.main import app

@app.task()
def create_params():
    """Prepare params needed to query the api"""
    ...
    return "x", "y", "z"

@app.task()
def fetch_data(q_params):
    """Fetch the data"""
    ...
    x, y, z = q_params
    return f"Data to write from querying api with {x, y, z}"

@app.task()
def write_data(data):
    """Write data to db"""
    ...
    return f"WRITTEN DATA - {data}"


@app.task
def update_data():
    """Fetch data, and store in db"""
    return (create_params.s() | fetch_data.s() | write_data.s())()

…
```

```py
# scheduler.py
from celery.schedules import crontab

from my_proj.main import app
from my_proj.tasks import update_data

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    """Set up cron like schedules for tasks to be run on a regular basis"""

    # add your periodic tasks here
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour="*/2", minute="0"),
        update_data.s(),
        name="update data every 2 hours",
    )
```

My question is: Is it OK to have a task that is a chain of tasks?